# puppy linux R stats sh: -f command not found

Tags: linux, r

I have recently installed a persistent version of puppy "tahrpup" on a usb. I want to run R stats on the system, however there have been some problems. The first issue was that the deb file I installed for r-cran-base did not make a Renviron file in its own library. After I sorted that and pointed to the correct place the library is supposed to be, I am now having the problem of not being able to compile packages downloaded through the R software.

I get a "sh: -f: command not found" error for every package and then it exits with error. My hunch is that the issue lies in the Makeconf file but I am unsure what to do. I have already installed r-cran-dev and make on the system, but it is still not compiling downloaded packages.

Comment: Make sure Java is installed as well. I ran into some issues with Linux Mint before because of that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have rJava and jdk 7 installed on the system.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention though that I have tried compiling R from source, I get through configure but when I go to make it fails with cannot find JNI. Could these two problems be related?

Comment: Maybe: [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Comment: Update: Try to configure rjava with R CMD javareconf fails because there are variables that cannot be evaluated and then JNI cannot be compiled because a command cannot be found. I have JDK installed and I have set the paths to it and javac.

Comment: I actually gave up on this and used Ubuntu Mate, which worked fine on a live persistent USB.